# How can the abc conjecture put constraints on the prime factors of $c$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization, abc-conjecture

> Let $c = a + b$ be an abc-triple $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\text{gcd}(a,b,c) = 1$, with the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$ known. How can the abc conjecture put constraints on the prime factors of $c$?

I am interested of the 'practical' use of the abc conjecture. I found this nice reddit post: [Why would solving the ABC conjecture be of importance to us?](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5u7hj4/why_would_solving_the_abc_conjecture_be_of/), where the commenter explained that even if the factorizations of $a$ and $b$ are known, it is still very difficult to say something about the prime factorization of $c = a + b$. And that the abc conjecture could give constraints on the factors in $c$ in this case, but I don't see how.

I appreciatie references.

Comment: Suppose, say, that $a=p^n$ and $b=q^n$. Then the explicit abc-conjecture (with FLT as a corollary) gives a restriction on the prime decomposition of $c$. It can't be an $n$-th power.